Installing OpenStack single guided accessible from outside host
I installed OpenStack Snap single mode using this guide:
https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#single-multi-large-cluster
sudo snap install openstack --channel 2024.1/edge

At the end I could reach Horizon only from the host using the text-browser w3m.
I searched the net for the problem and found iptables routings to get access to the internal network. My Ubuntu-Host is using nft, so I learned nft and set the route with dnat.
but I could not get access to horizon :-(
I tested my rules by setting web.de as target. That worked. But internaly it did not.
Now I found the guided version of installation.
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/single-node-guided/35765
The only difference seems to be that a switch at the end is missing: "sunbeam cluster bootstrap" without  --accept-defaults at the end.
My questions:

Can I run "sunbeam cluster bootstrap" again over the installed
version with  --accept-defaults
how does this "floating IPs" work? Is it just giving /24 or
something appropriate at the end? There must be some kind of routing
so that I can reach VMs etc. from outside the internal net.
During my last installation the file demo-openrc was created. That
contained credentials for keystone. What do I have to do after
installation finished? Next Steps?
Is there a more detailed documentation out there? Most resources I find are very old.

I am entering a whole new universe using OpenStack. Proxmox is a tiny thing compared to this...
